Permanent Image Specifics - Movement Rules
What does movement means within the context of the Permanent Image spell (or, in fact, entire family of Image spells, which Permanent Image seems to be the peak of)?

Is movement in X axis allowed?
Is movement in Y axis allowed?
Is movement in Z axis allowed?
Is zooming in/out allowed?
Is rotating along X/Y/Z axis allowed?

What is illusion attached to when caster is not concentrating on moving it? Can it be attached to, let's say, a cart or a ship? So that it travels with the caster wherever he goes? Can it be attached to caster himself? After all ground is just a part of big rock levitating in nothingness or space, thus not really different from any other object.
Is "animating" (as in character motions, like illusion of a standing guard, breathing, scratching his back, smoking pipe, etc.) considered movement that needs concentration or is this just part of the spell and movement starts when entire block is supposed to move to other coordinates?
Mind that, while it looks like several questions, it's actually one consistent question pointing out long list of unspecified details within the spell that need clarification.
Only RAW answers please. Or as close to RAW as one can get, given how many things Paizo themselves left unanswered.

You may be interested in answers to this question. And, although for Pathfinder's antecedent, you may be also be interested in this question.

Related: Can Silent Image move with a character?

You can move it, but need to concentrate to do so
You want "only Rules as Written", for things where there are not a lot of rules written. The open ended nature of illusions is that they typically require a lot of GM discretion, or negotiation and agreement off-table between GM and players of how they will be handled and what is possible. With that said, here is the Rules as Written on Permanent Image:

This spell functions like silent image, except that the figment includes visual, auditory, olfactory, and thermal elements, and the spell is permanent. By concentrating, you can move the image within the limits of the range, but it is static while you are not concentrating.

Range long (400 ft. + 40 ft./level). And the referenced Silent Image is a concentration duration spell that says:

This spell creates the visual illusion of an object, creature, or force, as visualized by you. The illusion does not create sound, smell, texture, or temperature. You can move the image within the limits of the size of the effect.

Not a lot to go by regarding movement. As these illusions are figments, the rules for those say, as the closest thing that could relate to movement:

Likewise, you cannot make a visual copy of something unless you know what it looks like (or copy another sense exactly unless you have experienced it).

That is it. To your detailed questions.
Where can you move it? There is no limitation about where or how in range to move the image. You can move it to anywhere within 400 feet plus 40 feet per level, sideways or up or down. You can turn it in any direction. If you can zoom it in or out is a debate with your GM on what it means to create a visual copy. Is a minimized version still a copy? There are no rules written for that.
Will the illusion move when you do not concentrate on it? No, it is static while you are not concentrating. Static as per the dictionary means "lacking in movement, action, or change". An illusory goblin will look like a goblin, but without any movement - no breathing, blinking etc.
Can you attach it to something? There are no rules that say you can "attach" the illusion to anything, so when you are not actively moving it, it will not move. It is not a real thing. If you make it appear on a cart, and the cart moves away on the battlefield, as written it would stay behind (but again, check with your GM how you want to handle it). One exception I see is with very large objects, like ships, that essentially constitute the entire battlefield. These typically are used as a frame of reference for practical purposes of play, like the planet you are on, and they would be static in reference to them, the illusions would not move off of them slowly because the planet is turning.
You also should be aware that if you move an illusion in a way the thing you depict could not, like just moving a goblin's image up 20 feet into the air, it may make opponents suspect something is wrong, and study it carefully or try to interact with it so they can disbelieve it.

Technically planet moves, so for Illusion to stay in one place it would actually move relative to the ground. All movement is relative. That's why I specified in my question: if it can be attached to the ground, can it be attached to any other object? Long story short I'd like to at least know if transporting my Permanent Illusion with me is possible or not.

@NecXelos It is not a new discussion if you can apply these kinds of physics rules to the game and I think beyond the specific scope of this question to discuss in detail, because these would also apply to many other magical static effects like gates, rope tricks etc. See here for example, or here. You need to concentrate if you want to move your permanent illusion around. Also, note you can only move it within range, so if you are travelling longer distances...

That's another issue. Is center point of range the caster so when caster moves so does the center of the spell or is the center point of range static, this allowing caster to move to the other side of the planet while spell effect remains in original place? That doesn't seem to be specified anywhere either. I wish community came up with something like UNIVERSAL COMMUNITY FAQ and then print it and keep proding Paizo employees with it until someone signs it thus making it official.

@NecXelos Yes, that might well be a good other question. This one already has too many different questions for what the stack prefers  lumped together into one, related or not. Any one of them, like if you can attach an illusion to something, or how range works after casting, would be better explored as a separate one. For what its worth, the rules say "You make all pertinent decisions about a spell (range, target, area, effect, version, and so forth) when the spell comes into effect.", so you set the range when you cast the spell, but I agree, it would be better to explore that deeper.

@NecXelos Out of curiosity, what difference does it make if a ruling on a dead game line with no extant organized play structure is official or not? At this point in the game's life cycle, it seems awfully safe (i.e. play can continue unimpeded and uncontroversially) for the GM to rule on ambiguities and, when you run your own campaign, to rule differently if you didn't like that GM's ruling. Why the focus on the official rather than the reasonable or playable? (This is not a play-style slam, especially coming from me! I'm genuinely interested in your gaming. Is it GMless arena style?)

I'm simply against the very idea of GM being above rules and will never accept it. So does my group and majority of groups I play in/with. And that's also my philosophy as a GM. Yes, sometimes there's no choice, but I'm going to milk/squeeze every last drop of RAW until I accept defeat and admit there has to be a debate between GM and players about some rule (or lack thereof). It's not the place to discuss that, but long story short: "book is sacred" is a very good approach for plethora of reasons, competition between player characters being near top of the list. Let the better player win.

@NecXelos re vehicles as an example of a moving target, the Skull & Shackles Players Guide (on p16-18) has a list of how various spells interact with moving ships.  The only illusion explicitly mentioned is Mirage Arcana, which can treat a ship as a "structure" and move with it, the examples of which spells do move with a ship and which are stationary may give some guidance to the GM - though most of those which move are explicitly cast on an object rather than a location.  Ultimate Combat is sadly lacking in guidance in the chapter on vehicle combat.
